# accessing individual arguments of a variable list of arguments in R

Tags: r

I'm aware that you can have a function which receives variable number of arguments as
follows. Assume I pass the age, gender and marks of **any** number of courses to a function, how do I print out the marks which is part of the variable argument list?

```
myvarfunction = function(id,age,...)
{
    print(id)
    print(age)

    #How do I print out the marks
}

myvarfunction(1,21)

#Assume these are the marks passed(number of courses unknown, so I have a variable number of args)
myvarfunction(1,21,97)
myvarfunction(1,21,97,96)
myvarfunction(1,21,97,96,999)
```

Comment: Add `as.list(...)` in there to capture these args.

Comment: @TylerRinker, thanks, I used just varargs = list(...). as.list was printing only the first argument. But why am I not able to print varargs outside the function? varargs gets printed only within the function body(block)

Comment: @TylerRinker , sorry that's a generic question I guess, not related to the topic. Was able to do it using varargs <<- list(...)

Comment: Generally, `print` inside of a function is not helpful.  Usually you want to `return` it at the end.  You can also return a list as in: `return(list(a=10, b="dog", c=rnorm(10)))`.  `print` just sends to the console.

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions I would suggest:

```
match_call <- function(...) match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)[["..."]]
eval_alist <- function(...) eval(substitute(alist(...)))
```

Note that `match_call` will give a 'dotted pair' list:

```
> str(match_call(a = 1, b = 2, 3))
Dotted pair list of 3
 $ a: num 1
 $ b: num 2
 $  : num 3
```

while `eval_alist` will give a plain `list`:

```
> str(eval_alist(a = 1, b = 2, 3))
List of 3
 $ a: num 1
 $ b: num 2
 $  : num 3
```

and `unlist` will return it either set as a vector (if you so desire)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
myvarfunction <- function(id, age, ...){
  obj <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  print(id)
  print(age)
  invisible(sapply(obj, print))
}

 myvarfunction(1,21)
 #[1] 1
 #[1] 21

myvarfunction(1,21,97,96)
#[1] 1
#[1] 21
#[1] 97
#[1] 96

myvarfunction(1,21,97,96,999)
#[1] 1
#[1] 21
#[1] 97
#[1] 96
#[1] 999
```

Or as suggested by @Tyler Rinker

```
myvarfunction <- function(id, age, ...){
 obj <- unlist(list(...))
  print(id)
  print(age)
 invisible(sapply(obj, print))
}

myvarfunction(1,21,97,96,999)
#[1] 1
#[1] 21
#[1] 97
#[1] 96
#[1] 999
```

Comment: Is this cleaner maybe: `unlist(list(...))`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `list(...)`. This puts all the extra arguments into a list.

```
myvarfunction = function(id,age,...)
{
    print(id)
    print(age)
    print(list(...))
}
```